# Github repo/local repo and web release stuff

Tags: linux, github, permissions, apache2, release

So my plan of my project is. im working on homeAutomation system and im starting to make WebControl panel and im  hosting it on my own local server with apache2. i want make repository of my ControlPanel but i think it isnt recommended to deploy in apache folders /var/www/my-domain-name and those permissions and who owns apache2 /var/www etc files is good to be default root or www-data right?

if i make my repo in /home/my-user location in linux and i develop it there and i make pulls and pushes to github from there. is there some simple solution to release that version from github into /var/www/my-domain location without cloning repo /var/www location.

Whats simple solution how should i do this?

one thing i was thinking that if i change /var/www/my-domain folder permissions for my own User then i dont have any issues saving my code from VSC. (im remotely developing it with ssh). but is it bad if i change ownership of that domain from root or www-data to my own user.

and i could make repo with my domain and clone it into /var/www but i dont want my repo name be same as my domain